# powershell code to create user and adding them to groups on AD server

Tags: powershell, active-directory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXf4J.png)I am begineer in powershell, trying to develop script for creating user and adding user to the multiples groups as array, unable to print the **ResponseMessage: Successfull- User " +$UPN+ " is already present on the $grp** even the member is already added on the group its not going to catch i think, correct the logic i was missed something. Thanks in advance

```
Param
(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $fname,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $lname,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string] $initials,
   [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [string] $desc,
   [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [string] $Email,
   [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [string] $password,
   [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [string[]] $Group
)
# Define UPN
$UPN = "c-$fname.$lname@examp.com"
$SamAccount = "$fname.$lname"
$ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$SamAccount'" | Select-Object SamAccountName
#$ADGroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * | Select-Object Name
#Adding user on AD

Try
{
    #if (!($ADUser)){
   New-ADUser -GivenName "$fname" -Surname "$lname" -Initials $initials -displayName "${fname} ${lname}" -UserPrincipalName $UPN -Description "$desc" -Name "$fname $lname" -EmailAddress "$email" -SamAccountName $SamAccount -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -AccountPassword $(ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force) -Enabled $false -Path "OU=aws,DC=azureicmp,DC=com" -Server "AzureDomain"
   "ResponseMessage: successfull- User " +$UPN+ " added to the AD"
#}
}
Catch 
    { 
        $message = $Error.Exception.message
        if ($message.Contains("The specified account already exists"))
        {
            "ResponseMessage: Successfull- User " +$UPN+ " is already present on the AD"
        }
        else 
        {
            $message
            "ResponseMessage: Error- Adding user on the AD has issues"
        }
    }
  

#Adding user to the group
Try
{
 foreach ($grp in $Group)
   {
     $grp = $grp.tostring()
     #Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $grp -Members $SamAccount
     #Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $grp -Members $ADUser
     #"ResponseMessage: Successfull- User " +$UPN+ " added to the $grp"
     Continue
    }
}
Catch
    { 
        $message = $Error.Exception.message
        if ($message.Contains("The specified account already exists"))
        {
            "ResponseMessage: Successfull- User " +$UPN+ " is already present on the $grp"
        }
        else 
        {
            #$message
            "ResponseMessage: Error- Adding user on the group has issues"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Script is not syntactically valid (missing closing quotes on `$SamAccount = "$fname.$lname`) by the looks of it. Please correct it

Comment: sorry its my bad typing mistake i have edited the above script

Comment: Thanks. Try with `Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $grp -Members $ADUser -EA Stop` <- the `-EA Stop` part should make the command throw a terminating that the `catch` block can catch

Comment: ResponseMessage: Successfull- User c-usha.d@icmp.com is already present on the AD-this one is clear
ResponseMessage: Successfull- User c-usha.d@icmp.com added to the admin -user is already added for the first run it should be print  **ResponseMessage: Successfull- User " +$UPN+ " is already present on the $grp**
ResponseMessage: Successfull- User c-usha.d@icmp.com added to the admin2                 -getting same thing attached img for ref

Comment: By using `$message.Contains(..)` you may restrict yourself too much, because for one thing, the Contains() method is case sensitive. Try `$message -like '*account already exists*'`. That and also, append `-ErrorAction Stop` to the cmdlets inside the try blocks, so the code will also enter the catch block when non-terminating errors occur. P.S. Have a look at using [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) so you can make beter readable code and do not have to write those horrible long lines.